# Python code in console has different result when code is placed in a script

Tags: python, console

I'm playing with **re module** and I have a difference of results I can't explain.

I have an input file containing the following text

> Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise System Performance Report
>
> Server Version:        Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 22639 SMP SP52 /P/ 
>                         Sun_svr4/OS 5.10/ase157sp5x/3293/64-bit/FBO/Wed May 21 0 
>                         2:49:14 2014
>   Run Date:              Mar 24, 2017
>   Sampling Started at:   Mar 24, 2017 12:16:01
>   Sampling Ended at:     Mar 24, 2017 12:31:01
>   Sample Interval:       00:15:00
>   Sample Mode:           No Clear
>   Counters Last Cleared: Mar 21, 2017 14:49:21
>   Server Name:           SYB01

I have the following python code where I want to get the line starting with 'Run Date:' (later I want to extract block of lines but let's proceed step by step)

```
import re
filename = 'D:/sp_sysmon/sp_sysmon_SYB01_170324_121544.txt'
file_r = open(filename,'r')
file_content = file_r.read()
print (file_content)

pattern_date = re.compile(r"Run Date:", re.MULTILINE)
bingo = pattern_date.search(file_content)
bingo.group()
```

If I execute this code directly in a python console I have the following

```
C:\Users\simon>python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC >v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>>
>>> filename = 'D:/sp_sysmon/sp_sysmon_SYB01_170324_121544.txt'
>>>
>>> file_r = open(filename,'r')
>>> file_content = file_r.read()
>>> print (file_content)
      Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise System Performance Report


Server Version:        Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 22639 SMP SP52 /P/
                       Sun_svr4/OS 5.10/ase157sp5x/3293/64-bit/FBO/Wed May 21 0
                       2:49:14 2014
Run Date:              Mar 24, 2017
Sampling Started at:   Mar 24, 2017 12:16:01
Sampling Ended at:     Mar 24, 2017 12:31:01
Sample Interval:       00:15:00
Sample Mode:           No Clear
Counters Last Cleared: Mar 21, 2017 14:49:21
Server Name:           SYB01

>>>
>>> pattern_date = re.compile(r"Run Date:", re.MULTILINE)
>>> bingo = pattern_date.search(file_content)
>>> bingo.group()
'Run Date:'
>>>
```

**This is the output I expect**

Now If copy this code in a script.py file and execute it, I have a different result where the call the bingo.group() doesn't show anything

```
D:\Perso\My_code\python>python script.py
      Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise System Performance Report
Server Version:        Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0/EBF 22639 SMP SP52 /P/
                       Sun_svr4/OS 5.10/ase157sp5x/3293/64-bit/FBO/Wed May 21 0
                       2:49:14 2014
Run Date:              Mar 24, 2017
Sampling Started at:   Mar 24, 2017 12:16:01
Sampling Ended at:     Mar 24, 2017 12:31:01
Sample Interval:       00:15:00
Sample Mode:           No Clear
Counters Last Cleared: Mar 21, 2017 14:49:21
Server Name:           SYB01 D:\Perso\My_code\python>
```

Does anybody have an ID of this difference?

Comment: That is because the REPL is _interactive_. If you type in an expression, the REPL will echo back the result. If you are running code from a script however, you have to explicitly print the value of `bingo.group()`: `print(bingo.group())`.

Comment: The Python interactive shell implements a REPL, which stands for a Read, Evaluate, and Print Loop. In a script, on the other hand, you have to call `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()` to read a line of input and `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` to write output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the result of that call.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
print(bingo.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interactive console, **after each command, a `repr()` of its result is printed** for your convenience.

This doesn't happen when executing a script, so you need to explicitly `print` whatever you want to be printed.

Comment: I'll now search for the normative reference.

Comment: Strange, nothing in the docs. Probably considered that a trivial detail.